# How does initializing an integer as "a = {1,}" compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax

I found this weird syntax:

```
int a = {1,};
```

And it works in all the compilers I've tried. How does it compile?

EDIT: I thought that scalar initializers can only have one element in it, spawning my question. Sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: Please do everyone a favor, and don't let the author of that line get away unpunished. Call him/her to the water cooler, roll up a newspaper, whack him/her and say "No! Bad! Bad programmer!"

Comment: @DanielKO Of what line?

Comment: The line you posted, `int a = {1,};`, you said you found it. It's a tongue-in-cheek way to say please don't ever write code like this, unless you are creating a submission for the IOCCC.

Answer (score 15):

As stated by Matt McNab in comments, the syntax of a braced initialized list is the same regardless of whether you are using it to initialize a scalar or anything else.

C++11 §5.17 states

> A braced-init-list may appear on the right-hand side of
>
> - an assignment to a scalar, in which case the initializer list shall have at most a single element.

The definition of braced-init-list is (from §8.5):

```
braced-init-list:
  { initializer-list ,opt }
  { }
```

where the 'opt' means that the trailing comma is optional.

Comment: N3337 is a draft, not an ISO standard.

Comment: Yes I know that. It's the only one I have access to however. I updated somewhat to clarify that.

Comment: +++1 Great answer to _this_ question not some other question.

Comment: @harmic I know you know that, I just found it weird how you put "ISO" for no discernable reason.

Comment: It's really usefull when initialiser/enums are on multiple lines. If you finish your list with comma and add a parameter, the diff is only on the new parameter line and not on the last two.